# Defining trees with unknown number of children

Tags: c++

I need to define a tree wherein the number of children every node has is unknown.
It cannot be done using an array because the number of children can be over or under estimated.
So I need to use a linked list where the list will be of children of the node.

How will this be done

```
class emp
{
    string name;
    emp* parent;
    employee* child;

};

struct employee
{
    emp* junior;
    employee* next;
};
```

In this code employee is not defined before employee child is called so it gives an error.
Please suggest changes.

Comment: Or you could use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Or make a generic linked list template. Or do it the C-like way and make a linked list using `(void*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declare `employee` before `emp` class definition.

```
struct employee;

class emp
{
  //....
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would say that you should use a `vector<employee>` or `list rather than building your own linked list.

Note also that using a linked list will add a fair amount of extra memory usage, because each node till have an overhead of, typically, 32-64 bytes.